# Cannot access 'ref' before initialization in react

Tags: reactjs

I've tried integrate Firebase to my App
I import:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue, set, push, child, remove } from 'firebase/database';
import {initializeFirebase} from './Firebase';
```

and call `getDatabase` in `render`. `getDatabase` is:

```
getDatabase =  () => {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const ref = ref(db, "data/")
  }
```

I got this problem "
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ref' before initialization". Why am I wrong, and how should I fix that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
const app = initializeApp({});
getDatabaseFunc =  () => {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const ref = ref(db, "data/")
  }
```

change the name of the main function to getDatabaseFunc or any other name different from getDatabase() to prevent overriding

Comment: I still get that error, and get a notification from vscode :  'await'  has no effect on the type of this expression

Comment: did you initialize firbase before using it

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup